# Rails auto-load ajax content

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have two models:

```
class Phase < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope order('created_at DESC')

  attr_accessible :created_at, :date_due, :name, :project_id, :status

  belongs_to :project
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :created_at, :name, :status, :company_id

  has_many :phases, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

On my project#show view, I'm using links set to :remote => true to load a single phase#show view at a time into a div.

**project#show runs this to find the phases:**

```
<% phases = Phase.where(:project_id => @project.id) %>
<% phases.each do |p| %>
  <div class="phase">
    <h3><%= link_to p.name, p, :class => "show_phase_link", :remote => true %></h3>
    <h5>Ends <%= p.date_due.strftime("%B %d, %Y") %></h5>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**And then some jquery loads the data into a div**

```
$('body').delegate("a.show_phase_link", "click", function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr("href"),
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
      //display phase
      $("#phase_content").html(data);
    }
  });
})
```

The problem is that when you get to the page, the div starts empty. I need to auto load the first phase that has status == "0", but can't seem to find how to begin to handle this one.

Thanks!!!

Comment: `<% phases = Phase.where(:project_id => @project.id) %>` Use this instead: `<% phases = @project.phases %>`

Comment: And you should trigger your ajax call on body's load. An awfull way but should be working : `$(document).ready(function(){ $('a.show_phase_link').first().click(); });`

Comment: That jquery will load the very first phase, regardless of status, but I've modified to make a special class on the links for status=="0" phases, which did the trick. Thanks! Don't know how I didn't see that one.